# Concurrent tasks but only for different type of tasks

Tags: go, concurrency

I have the following use-case where I struggle to identify the right concurrency pattern.

I have a service that has a list of computational tasks to do:

- Some are fast to execute (a few seconds), others can take hours
- I never want the same task to be executed twice at the same time
- Different tasks can be executed in parallel
- If one task is supposed to be refreshed every hour by example but at some point, it takes more than 1 hour to execute, I want to discard the new execution but log it somewhere
- I want to have a timeout on tasks

I'm fine with using an external library of course.

I looked at `singleflight` but this seems to be aimed at **caching** and new executions of a task will be blocked until this task finish computing. In my case, I want to log the fact that it was already computing but discard the new execution (or just not do it).

Comment: Great! That makes a lot of sense, Thanks a lot!

Comment: @Mike: The goroutine has to tell others that it's done. This is often done using something like a WaitGroup or a channel.

Comment: If you go ahead and add your answer I'll accept it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maintain a map of tasks in progress. When adding a task, check map and log if task is in progress; add task to map. Remove task from map when done.

Here's an example assuming that a task is identified by a `string` and implemented by a `func()`.

```
var (
    mu         sync.Mutex
    inProgress = map[string]bool{}
)

func startTask(id string, fn func()) {
    mu.Lock()
    ip := inProgress[id]
    if !ip {
        inProgress[id] = true
    }
    mu.Unlock()
    if ip {
        log.Printf("task %s in progress", id)
    } else {
        go func() {
            fn()
            mu.Lock()
            delete(inProgress, id)
            mu.Unlock()
        }()
    }
}
```